# How to count the JSON object and on the basis of count take the same output

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects, dom-events

1. How to count the JSON object and on the basis of count take the same     output

   ```
       var obj = 
      [
       {"id":"0","name":"Mike Johnson","group":1},
       {"id":"1","name":"Bob Smith","group":2},
       {"id":"2","name":"Richard Thomas","group":3},
       {"id":"3","name":"Betty White","group":16},
       {"id":"4","name":"Tim Thompson","group":3},
       {"id":"5","name":"Carl Lewis","group":16},
       {"id":"6","name":"Kathy Towers","group":3},
       {"id":"7","name":"Billy Bob","group":1},
       {"id":"8","name":"Sally Bailey","group":1}
       ];
   ```

   2. First I would like the count after it on the basis of count. I want                                         same output like input. 
      for Count:-

      ```
      var count = 0;
      function getCount() {

      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

              count++;

      }
      return count;
      }
      ```

   for output :-

   ```
   function showDetails()   this is not giving the proper output
   { 

      for(var j=0; j< count; j++){ 
      obj.push([{j}]);    
      }                   
   alert(obj.name);        
   }                      
   alert(showDetails());   
   And I want an output like:- 

        var obj = 
      [
       {"id":"0","name":"Mike Johnson","group":1},
       {"id":"1","name":"Bob Smith","group":2},
       {"id":"2","name":"Richard Thomas","group":3},
       {"id":"3","name":"Betty White","group":16},
       {"id":"4","name":"Tim Thompson","group":3},
       {"id":"5","name":"Carl Lewis","group":16},
       {"id":"6","name":"Kathy Towers","group":3},
       {"id":"7","name":"Billy Bob","group":1},
       {"id":"8","name":"Sally Bailey","group":1}
       ];
   ```

   Can anybody  help me please?

Comment: var array = new Array(string);

Comment: it does not give the output as i show you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var str = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October";

var arr = str.split(',').map(function(v) {
 return {name: v};
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Good ECMA5 solution

Comment: @Arvind welcome, please accept any answer which solved your problem)

Comment: ok bro and i also ask one question can u provide the solution of it.

Comment: @ArvindChaudhary yes, please ask now if possible.. I'll be away shortly

Answer (score 4):

```
var data ="January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October";
var obj = data.split(',').map((item)=>{
     return {
           name:item
           }
});
```

`obj` will be the desired output

Comment: This appears to use js syntax which not all browsers currently support.

Comment: Yeahh true. This is the `ECMA6 arrow function expression`. In near future, hopefully all browser will provide support

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October";
var months = str.split(",");
var result = [];


for (i in months)
{
   var month = {};
   month.name = months[i];
   //you can do more things else here, for example:
   //month.monthOfYear = (i+1);
   //month.numberOfDay = 123123123;
   result.push(month);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var array = string.split(",");
var finalArray = [];

array.forEach(function(item){

   var obj = {
        name: item
   }

   finalArray.push(obj);

});

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more ES2015 heavy version. Constants, arrow function and implicit return statement.

```
const str = 'January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October'
const result = str.split(',').map(name => ({name}))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

use `var array = string.split(',');`